# searching through dictionary with list and string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, reference

I have a dictionary(see below) with string as key and list as the values. How can I reference the contents of the list to get the key?

```
number_dict = {'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 'tens': ['ten','twenty','thirty','forty'],
'hundreds':['hundred']}
```

so I tried

```
if number_dict.values()[0]=="one":
    print(number_dict.key[0])
```

and I would have expected "digits" as an output.Instead I get:

TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would opt for a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
number_dict = {'digits': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
               'tens': ['ten','twenty','thirty','forty'],
               'hundreds':['hundred']}
```

```py
[key for key, value in number_dict.items() if 'two' in value]
```

Comment: fantastic. It works a treat. What's the best way to learn list comprehension. It looks so cool:)

Comment: good question. it took me a while to get my head around it. I learnt though trial and error. [This is a great resource](https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php) as well. If this code helps consider up-voting and accepting it as the answer to help other members.

Comment: thanks a lot. I upvoted, but becaue I am new, so I guess thats why it hasn't counted.sorry about that..I'll get more involved here and get back to you